# Android local storage

Tags: android, storage, local

I have a problem with a webview which may access to the localStorage by app. My index.html informs that local storage is'nt supported by my browser (ie. the webview). If you have any suggestion.. Please take a look at my code :

**Activity.java**:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidHTML;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myBrowser;
;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 

        WebSettings webSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();
        //enable JavaScript in webview
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Enable and setup JS localStorage
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.exercise.AndroidHTML"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidHTMLActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set the database path:

webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

Answer (score 1):

setDatabasePath() method was deprecated in API level 19. I advise you to use storage locale like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}
```