# Unique device web fingerprinting amongst 10-20 company tablets

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, tablet

I am trying to implement a QR coding technique at my company. This involves scanning a QR code with an android tablet, and I would like to have certain devices at each station to record information. Is there a very accurate way with javascript or another web framework, which I can edit/create/or log a unique device identifier which can than be read client or server side to log which device this is coming from once the webpage is reached from the QR code?

Comment: There is no short answer on that topic. Look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757105/javascript-how-to-check-user-agent-for-mobile-tablet  or https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect

Comment: these tablets would be all the same type of tablets, which makes it seem as if this method wouldnt work

Comment: If you have control over the used tabels, how about useing HTML5 Local Storeage http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp or cookies or fixed IP's  to unifie them in the first place?

Comment: will this local storage method work on android tablets? I may try with cookies. IP addressing isnt a bad method, but i will use that as a last resort scenario

Comment: `local storage method work?` Thing that depends on the OS not the device. Or save a file on the tablet that unifies and use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript. if i had a straight answer, i would write one :)

Comment: For android look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895880/android-local-storage

Comment: Thank you man I appreciate the help, Im testing these methods now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: No, what I am asking is if there is a way to access that unique android device ID via javascript